# RCA TABLET RESET

Tags: factory-reset, tablet

I am trying to reset my rca tablet. I just want to clean everything off. I tried holding the volume and power button. I told until dogs come up, then screen goes black for a second then dogs just come up again then goes black again then dogs. Then the regular log in screen comes up.

Comment: You were told to hold volume up button them briefly press the power button. Keep pressing the volume button.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions below to reset your RCA Tablet (Should work for every RCA models)

- With your tablet turned off, press and hold the volume up (+) button. While holding the volume up (+) button, press the tablet’s power button until you see the RCA logo with Nipper and Chipper on the screen. After a few seconds, the screen will change and you will see the Android bot on his back with a caution symbol above it.
- Now  press and hold the  power button, and without releasing the power button press down on the volume up (+) button.
- Use the  volume up (+) and down (+) keys to navigate to and select the **"wipe data/factory reset"** option. To select this option, press the power button.
- The device should ask you to confirm your selection. Use the  volume up (+) and down (-) keys to navigate to and select "**Yes – delete all user data**." Once again, use the power button to select this option.
- At the bottom of the next screen, you will see "***Data wipe complete***." Press the power button to restart the device.
- The device should begin to reboot and once again display the RCA logo with Nipper and Chipper. The next "Welcome" screen will prompt you to select your language of choice. Scroll through the options using your finger and press start when finished..

Comment: Actually it says hold power button UNTIL the screen changes, it does NOT say briefly hold the power button while still holding volume up, HENCE the confusion, so you might want to edit those instructions.